# How do I go about getting a file from my res folder within my project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, file, directory

I've been trying to get a file from my res folder within my project so that I can use it as a BufferedImage, but to no avail.

[image: Trying to get the file and use ImageIO to get a BufferedImage]

[image: This is the project so far - the image is under /res/img]

Running what I've done above throws an IllegalArgumentException (ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)).
This shouldn't happen unless getResourceAsStream is returning a null value, which means that I'm not getting the file from my res folder properly.
So overall, I'm a little lost on how to tackle this issue.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
return ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(new File("res/img/SmallDagger.png")));
```